# Pagination with Jquery/Javascript/Ajax and PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Does anyone know of a link to a site that has a tutorial/code on good way to paginate information coming from a database? (without page refresh) I have spent the better part of the day looking for a site that has what I need. Most are dealing with static/fixed data in the forms of lists etc.
I need one that has something like this for my tables:

```
Data          Data          Data          Data          

Data          Data          Data          Data          


Records 1 to 8 of 27  First  Previous Next Last
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just implemented a few things using this plugin for JQuery:

[Datatables.net](http://datatables.net/)

It works on basic html tables and has support for AJAX. Basically you would just write a PHP page that returns a partial result from your database in JSON, etc. The plugin will handle making the AJAX call and displaying the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im checking it out

Comment: I think [this page](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html) even has some sample PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a very partial answer (sorry, not much time atm) but look for the 'LIMIT' command in mysql.  It lets you pull back only a certain set of records, say records 11-20.  I use that when I do pagination.

Again, this isn't complete, but hopefully it'll help!

Comment: Thanks for they reply. Unfortunately that is not the problem. I guess I'm looking for a jQuery,Ajax plugin or tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with this one quite a bit. jQgrid... seems to be pretty well maintained.
http://www.trirand.com/blog/